# Sending event to specific property

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to send an event to a specific property on a page.  The page has multiple properties on it and I only want to raise this event in one specific property.

I have used `ga.getAll()` to see the properties on the page and the one I want is labeled `gtm3` so this is code I am trying:

```
  ga("gtm3.send", {
    hitType: "event",
    eventCategory: "Heartbeat",
    eventAction: "Beat",
    eventLabel: "Heartbeat",
    nonInteraction: true
  });
```

This does not work, debug mode gives me the message:

> command ignored. unknown target undefined

What did I do wrong?

I am testing this in console also so the tag is definitely registered.  Am I referencing it wrong?  In the `getAll()` I can see the property `name: "gtm3"`.

I am running this code on doc ready but have also tested direct in console so I don't think it is a timing issue.  What is proper way to reference this property and reference an event?

edit:

I also get the same message when I just run a simple: `ga('send', 'pageview');`

Why is target undefined?

Comment: Can you post the implementation code/snippet for GA?

Comment: It is implemented via GTM

Comment: If you're using GTM, then you shouldn't be doing things using ga(). ga() is for analytics.js

Comment: How do I fire an event from javascript then?

Comment: Do you have 3 different GTM snippets on the page?

Comment: no, one GTM but multiple GA properties added as tags

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182277/discussion-between-xtothel-and-guerrilla).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP was using Google Tag Manager as the method for GA implementation. Suggested to use DataLayer events to send the heart-beat event to GTM and utilize triggers within GTM to send the heart beat event to the appropriate GA property.

DataLayer Trigger on page:

```
....
DataLayer.push('event':'heart-beat');
....
```

The above is captured within GTM in a Custom Event trigger.

The Custom Event trigger is then used on a GA Event Tag set to non-interaction.